# How to solve $xy' + y + y^2 = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $xy' + y + y^2 = 0$

What substitution I should use? Letting $v = y+y^2$ doesn't seem to help.

Comment: $$\left(\frac{1}{xy}\right)'=-\frac{(xy)'}{(xy)^2}=-\frac{xy'+y}{(xy)^2}=\frac{1}{x^2}=\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)'$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is separable.  Rewrite it as $\int\frac{dx}x=\int f(y)dy$