# How to solve $xy'+y+x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $xy'+y+x=0$

I'm not sure what substitution to use. I don't think it separable or homogeneous?

Comment: And this other question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1670550/ gave you no idea whatsoever?

Comment: @Did well, I didn't read that obviously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, observe that $$xy'+y=xy'+x'y=(xy)'.$$ Thus, the equation is equivalent to $$(xy)'=-x.$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $xy=w$. We are solving $\frac{dw}{dx}=-x$.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to answer your question by inspection and here is my solution:

$$x\frac{dy}{dx}+y+x=0$$
$$xdy+(y+x)dx=0$$
$$(xdy+ydx)+xdx=0$$

By integration, we have,$$xy+\frac{x^2}{2}=C\ ,\ C\ as\ a\ constant\ no. $$
$$2xy+x^2=C$$

You can also use the Exact Differential Equation method.

Answer (score 0):

If you divide through by $x$, you can use the integrating factor method:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegratingFactor.html

$\frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{y}{x} = -1$

Let:

$P(x) = \frac{1}{x}$

$Q(x) = -1$

Then the integrating factor is:

$I(x) = e^{\int{P(x)}\,dx} = x$

Now, $y=\frac{1}{I(x)}(\int I(x)Q(x)\,dx)=\frac{\int -x\, dx}{x}$

Comment: but then the integrating factor would just be "x" though?

Comment: Yes - that's fine.

Comment: but then you are just multiplying what you divided by

Comment: No not quite. Once you have found the integrating factor, you have a formula for what $y$ equals.